# Error de push luego de renombrar commit localmente

Tags: git, github, push, repositorio

tengo un problema. Estaba pusheando a un repositorio en GitHub hasta que me di cuenta que en mi repositorio local escribí un "s" de mas en el "commit" que ya había pusheado a GitHub, entonces edite el commit con `git commit --amend -m` pero en la rama master de mi repositorio remoto no se habia hecho los cambios y creo que quizas ese es el problema porque me da error en mi terminal. Me aparece:

```html
$ git push
To https://github.com/mi_usuario/repositorio.git
 ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/mi_usuario/repositorio.git'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

Mientras que en mi git log me aparece.
nota: lg es mi alias para `git log --oneline --all --graph --decorate`

```html
$ git lg
* bf5e62b (HEAD -> main) Cambio 7
* 7c9cfe4 Cambio 7
* a640d2c Cambio 6
| * 5740d6a (origin/main) Cambios 6
|/
* 42ab924 Cambio 5
* f494650 Cambio 4
* 6a05b24 Cambios 3
```

No estoy seguro cual es el error que se me presenta, necesito una ayuda para subir mi commits renombrados desde mi repositorio local.

Comment: Si eres el único usuario del repositorio, haz `git push --force`. Si hay otros colaboradores que usen el remoto, debes coordinarte con ellos antes de hacer esto, pues a partir de ahi ellos podrían perder parte de su trabajo

Comment: El error es que `--amend` modifica la historia local. Reemplaza el commit (que ya estaba subido al remoto) por uno diferente. A partir de ahi `push`  falla porque el local y el remoto han divergido de forma irreconciliable. Mediante `push --force` fuerzas a que el remoto sea idéntico al original (sobreescribiendo entonces lo que hubiera en remoto). Moraleja: antes de hacer `push` fíjate bien que todo esté ok, no vayas a necesitar hacer un `--amend` (hacerlo antes del push no causa problemas)

Comment: Chevere ahora si ya me quedo mas claro. Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Me salio este error al primer **git push** de mi código y se corrigió con **git push -u origin main --force**

Gracias por la aportación @Robertiño

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-ask).